# MVC action method not triggered

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, routes

I have an MVC5 inventory web app with a list of items and a delivery button for each of them.

```
@foreach (var i in Model.Inventario)
{
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AggiungiAlloScarico", "Scarico"))
    {
        string Disabilitato = "";
        string Classe = "";
        // some method to define the buttons' styles

        <div class="pull-right">
            @Html.Hidden("Modello", i.Item.Modello)
            @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery)
            <input type="submit" class="@(String.Format("{0}", Classe))" value="Consegna" @Disabilitato />
        </div>
    }
}
```

At the click of any of those buttons, the `AggiungiAlloScarico` action method in the `Scarico` controller should be triggered. This method just adds the chosen item to an object within the session, then redirects the user to the `Index` view within the same controller, a sort of "cart" page where they could later choose to confirm or return to the original page.

```
[HttpPost]
public RedirectToRouteResult AggiungiAlloScarico(string Modello, string returnUrl)
{
    InventoryItem item = itemRepository.Inventario.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Item.Modello == Modello).Item;

    if (item != null)
    {
        GetScarico().AddItem(item, 1);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
}
```

The problem is that this action method isn't triggered at all. I thought that there might be something wrong with the routing, because every time I press the "Consegna" button I'm redirected to the `localhost:port/Scarico/AggiungiAlloScarico` page: that url construction corresponds to the default routing map (last method in the RoutConfig class), but the relevant action is not being called. Moreover, I put a breakpoint at the method but it never stops there so I guess here lies the problem, but I really can't see it.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        null,
        "",
        new { controller = "magazzino", action = "inventario", manufacturer = (string)null, page = 1 }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        null,
        "Page{page}",
        new { controller = "magazzino", action = "inventario", manufacturer = (string)null },
        new { page = @"\d+" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        null,
        "{manufacturer}",
        new { controller = "magazzino", action = "inventario", page = 1 }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        null,
        "{modello}",
        new { controller = "magazzino", action = "inventario", manufacturer = (string)null, page = 1 }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        null,
        "{manufacturer}/Page{page}",
        new { controller = "magazzino", action = "inventario" },
        new { page = @"\d+" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        null,
        "{manufacturer}/{modello}",
        new { controller = "magazzino", action = "inventario", page = 1 }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{action}");
}
```

All other routes were created to deal with the filtering and navigating system, which works good.

**EDIT:**
I commented out all the routes but the default ones, and it works. What's wrong with my customized routes?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Davide.

Comment: Do you have the necessary `[HttpPost]` attribute on the method?

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes. Adding that to the original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order in which the routes are added matters. The routing engine will take the first route that matches the supplied URL and attempt to use the route values in that route. Try to annotate the action method with Attribute Routing, if this works, then mostly it should be with the order of the routes.